# Enable OAuth2.0 in Grafana Infinity plugin for Citrix data source

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, grafana, citrix, infinity

I am trying to collect data from REST API using Grafana plug-ins (Infinity, Simple JSON, JSON), The problem is in order to access the API you should maintain a valid OAuth Token which expires every hour and should be refreshed, and it should be pre-fixed by certain word,
EX: 'Authorization' : 'Bearer *AUTHTOKEN*'

Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: That depends on what kind of _authentication_ your Grafana server uses. Grafana offers several authentication options. Identify the one yours uses first. This documentation might help: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/.

Comment: I want to collect data from an external API to Grafana, the Token expires every 4 hours, I want to do a refresh every 4 hours and the auth token should be prefixed by certain word  as per the source api documentation, it's OAuth2 which requires user ID and secret.

Comment: You'd better share the API documentation link.

Comment: This is the link:  https://developer.cloud.com/citrix-cloud/citrix-cloud-api-overview/docs/citrix-cloud-api-walkthrough#set_environment_variables_python

Answer (score 2):

1. Your Grafana Infinity plugin wants to access the protected Citrix data source.
2. Citrix is protected with the OAuth 2.0 *client credentials grant*: that means, Citrix clients must collect a *short-lived access token* by *authenticating themselves* with their id and secret and requests to Citrix APIs must include the access token as a *bearer token* (as the HTTP `Authorization` header prefixed with `Bearer` ).
3. [Creating an API client](https://developer.cloud.com/citrix-cloud/citrix-cloud-api-overview/docs/get-started-with-citrix-cloud-apis#create-an-api-client) in Citrix gives you your client id, client secret, and additionally, customer id.
4. Grafana Infinity plugin supports [client credentials grant](https://sriramajeyam.com/grafana-infinity-datasource/wiki/authentication) out of the box, meaning once you have Infinity [configured](https://sriramajeyam.com/grafana-infinity-datasource/wiki/configuration) with the required parameters (those you got while creating your client in Citrix), it will collect the token and include it as a bearer token for you.
5. The Infinity plugin documentation doesn't explicitly mention how it handles access token *expiration*: possibly it *requests for a new access token* if it detects that the access token has expired (the expiration time is returned as the `expires_in` value with the access token).

Comment: Can I achieve the above using Grafana, I did already using python but not sure gow to implement it in Grafana (Infinity plug-in).

Comment: Then your real question seems to be _authenticating Grafana Infinity plugin to an external data source_ (the data source in your case being citrix) so that it can make authenticated requests for data to the source. Did I get you right?

Comment: If that is your intention, you have to configure the Infinity plugin authentication accordingly. _The Infinity plugin_ supports [OAuth2 Client Credentials Authentication](https://sriramajeyam.com/grafana-infinity-datasource/wiki/authentication). You just have to set your parameters (which you received in step 1 of my answer) in the [configuration](https://sriramajeyam.com/grafana-infinity-datasource/wiki/configuration) page.

Comment: If I got you right, confirm and update the question accordingly please. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Exactly, this is my intention.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to follow these steps, if you have already logged in through any `OAuth` mechanism:

1. Go to Configuration > Data sources.
2. Add data sources, and select `Infinity`.
3. In authentication select `Forward OAuth` and add some Allowed host. For instance http://:8080/ to allow
   any data coming form the quarkus app.
4. Save and exit, the url will be set in the dashboard.